# The Arizal and the Ramak

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

What are the basic conceptual differences between the Lurianic school of kaballah and the Kordovero school of kaballah?

Comment: The "politically correct" answer is that there is not conflict ans the former picks up where the latter leaves off. AFAIK this is false.

Comment: This question is likely too broad. An entire book could likely be written to answer it.

Comment: In sefer Maasse Rav there is a known sentence of the Gaon Mivilna, +- The Kabbala of the Ramak begins where the More Nevuchim ends, the Kabbala of the Ari begins where the kabbala of the Ramak ends. From this phrase which is a bit laconic, we can understand that the domain is different.

Comment: In Gershon Scholem's book on Shabtai Tzvi he mentions derech agav that they don't shtim with each other. I was wondering how.

Comment: @MarkA. Consider editing that into the question itself.